# Oracle PL/SQL: Help resolving "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following: if"

Tags: oracle, plsql

See Second Edit. New coding gets different error.

I am getting the "encountered a loop when expecting an if" error. My goal is to return a list of tables that have been updated by a specific project_id. The project_id is stored in a column on each table labeled project_id.

I used a with statement to create 2 tables. One table (sb_table) is a single column of all the tables that I want to look at. There are many more tables, but I figured it would speed things up if I narrowed down the list first.  The other table I am creating (project) returns a single value turning the prjt_name provided into the actual project number (don't ask me why, but this is how my company has it set up, user creates a prct_name and is never aware of the project number).

Then I am trying to loop through the tables to see if they have the project number in their project_id column. If they do not, I delete them from the sb_table.

Ultimately, I am going to want to get all of the updated rows from all of the updated tables, but I am currently stuck on getting a list of the updated tables.

```
declare
query varchar2(10000);
table_count NUMBER;
update_count number;
prjt_name varchar2 not null := "01213264B";
cursor my_cur is select sbt.table_name from sb_table sbt;

begin

with sb_tables as (select table_name from all_tab_columns@db2 where 
                    column_name = 'PROJECT_ID' and owner = 'SANDBOX'),
    project as (select project_id from sandbox.sb_project@db2 where 
               project_name = upper(prjt_name))

--select sbt.table_name
--from sb_table sbt
    for tableName in my_cur loop

  query := 'select count(t.project_id) as "CNT" '||
                'from sandbox.' || tableName || '@db2 t, project p '||
                ' where  t.project_id = p.project_id  ';
Execute immediate query
 into update_count;

if update_count <= 0 then
     query := 'DELETE FROM sb_tables where table_name = ' || tableName;
     execute immediate query ;


end loop;
end;
```

Edit 1: Per comments, moved the select statement to the declare and am looping through my_cur now. I still get the same error.

Edit 2: Updated coding based on suggestions. I now get a different error message.

```
NEW ERROR: ORA-06550: line 12, column 16:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
ORA-06550: line 12, column 7:
```

Edit 3: I was missing an = in my sub query which produced the error "Missing expression at line 13."

Edit 4: Now I get some results then error out with the following message

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04040: file ext_qsp_benefit.dat in DATA_DIR not found
ORA-02063: preceding 3 lines from ADHOC_POS15
ORA-06512: at line 13
```

Edit 5: Success! Apparently I cannot query certain tables. So I just took those tables out.

Final coding is:

```
declare
  query varchar2(10000);
  update_count integer := 0;
  prjt_name varchar2(100) := '01213264B';
  cursor my_cur is (select table_name from all_tab_columns@db2 where column_name = 'PROJECT_ID' and owner = 'SANDBOX' and table_name in ('X') );
  tableName  varchar2(100);
begin
  open my_cur;
    loop
    fetch my_cur into tableName;
    exit when my_cur%NOTFOUND;
        update_count := 0;
        execute immediate
        'select count(project_id) as "CNT" from sandbox.' || tableName || '@db2  '
        || ' where project_id = (select project_id from sandbox.sb_project@db2 where project_name = ''' || prjt_name || ''' ) '
        into update_count;
    if update_count > 0 then
      dbms_output.put_line (tableName);
    end if;
  end loop;
  close my_cur;
end;
```

This doesn't do exactly what I wanted. It sends the results to dbms_output. But It is a start! Thanks everyone for you help!

Comment: You are missing a `;` for your `select` statement right _before_ the `for`

Comment: put your select into a named cursor in the declare section (declare...cursor my_cur is select ...) then in begin block loop through it (begin...for rec in my_cur LOOP ...)

Comment: Thanks Tbone. Unfortunately, that has not solved my problem. I still get the same error. See my updated code in the original comment.

Comment: @tparker If this is the current version of the block, it looks like it doesn't close its `IF`.  Have you tried adding and `END IF;` just after the line with `execute immediate query;`?

Comment: @tbone - I get what you are saying now. I did not execute that correctly. I have fixed it and updated my code above.

Comment: No, the "with" is part of your select too, although you shouldn't use "with" clause it at all, you should probably just join to whatever tables you need in your select statement (or you could use multiple selects if needed).  I'll try to give an example later today...

Comment: @tbone. Sorry. I got pulled away and wasn't able to attach my new coding. Thanks you your suggestion and alexgibbs, I am now just getting a type mismatch. I am not good enough with SQL to know how to fix that either, unfortunately.

Comment: upper (' should be upper(''' and ')) ' should be ''))'

Comment: All the quotes are confusing it. Every other quote exists the string. '* upper(' is the end of the string. '* upper(''' is the end of a string with an empty string right at the end. ')) ' is a string with 2 parenthesis.  ''))' is an empty string with 2 parenthesis next to it and an open ended string at the end. at least that is how is is being parsed by my ide.

Comment: @tparker Its not an empty string. It is an escape character. For ex:- where name = 'SOMENAME'.. To give the above inside a string, you should write like this 'Where name = ''SOMENAME'''. You have done that for CNT (''CNT'') in your query

Comment: to simplify things I took out the upper. I replaced that whole sercion to be like '* project_name = "prjt_name" )'. O sill get the error "missing expression at line 15"

Comment: @tparker it should be where project_name = "' || prjt_name ||"' ) '

Comment: @tparker and you should have a preceding space for where in 'where  t.project_id ...' It should be like ' where  t.project_id ..'

Comment: Still get the same errorafter updating.

Comment: @tpaarker, it is two single quotes and not double quotes. Please check my answer below.

Comment: And why did you comment out the declaration of prjtname?

Comment: I was toying with not using the variable at all and just plugging the user value in. I updated to single quotes. still get the same error.

Comment: Missing expression at line 15? I would suggest you to  Comment out the execute immediate part and just print the query. Try running that query in a console and see whats the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE
    update_count integer := 0;
    prjt_name varchar2(100) := 'tttt';
    mysql varchar2(100);
                   tablename  varchar2(100);

    cursor my_cur is 
         select 'DUAL' 
            from dual
           where 'PROJECT_ID' = 'PROJECT_ID' and 'SANDBOX' = 'SANDBOX';

begin
    open my_cur;
    LOOP
    FETCH  my_cur into tablename;
      EXIT WHEN my_cur%NOTFOUND;
        update_count := 0;
        mysql := 'select count(*)  ' || ' from '
        || tablename
        || ' where  ''TTTT'' = upper('''
        || prjt_name
        || ''')' ;
      Execute immediate mysql INTO update_count;
        dbms_output.put_line (mysql);

  dbms_output.put_line (update_count);
  END LOOP;
CLOSE my_cur;
end;
```

I tried one like yours. This executes successfully

---

```
declare
    query varchar2(10000);
    update_count integer := 0;
    prjt_name varchar2(100) := '01213264B';
    cursor my_cur is 
           select table_name 
             from all_tab_columns@adhoc_pos15 
             where column_name = 'PROJECT_ID' and owner = 'SANDBOX';
    tableName  varchar2(100);
begin
  open my_cur;
    loop
    fetch my_cur into tableName;
    exit when my_cur%NOTFOUND;
        update_count := 0;
        query := 'select count(t.project_id) as ''CNT'' from sandbox.'
        || tableName
        || '@adhoc_pos15 t'
        || ' where  t.project_id = (select project_id from sandbox.sb_project@adhoc_pos15 where project_name = ''' || prjt_name || ''') ' ;
   execute immediate query into update_count;
     dbms_output.put_line (query);
     dbms_output.put_line (update_count);
  end loop;
close my_cur;
end;
```

Comment: I really appreciate you trying to help me on both my questions. For this one. Updating to your suggestion to fetch and use dbms_output takes me back to my original error message. Now I am back to PLS-00103: encountered symbol loop.

Comment: Which one are you running now? There is no 'end if ' in your first script

Comment: I take back what I said before. This is getting close. I am now getting SQL command not ended properly at line 19. which is execute immediate query into update_count;

Comment: query := 'select count(t.project_id) as "CNT" from sandbox.' || tableName || '@db2 t, project p '||
                'where  t.project_id = (select project_id from sandbox.sb_project@db2 where project_name = upper(''' || prjt_name || '''))'

Comment: So its the issue with the way you form query string.. You have to pass prjt_name as value..

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Can you explain. Also, if I swap my query for the one you provided above I am getting missing right parenthesis error.

actually that is happening because project table no longer exists. Getting rid of that gets rid of that error. but my error is missing expression.

Comment: you have missed few quotes.. see my comment above

Comment: Finally, it got executed? :-)

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! The quotes thing was key. Switching to fetching was a huge help. I posted my updated code in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried your code with some execution, but before that you need to correct your with clause query. below code has executed except with  clause so, make some change dependence on your requirements.

```
**code :**

declare
query varchar2(10000);
table_count NUMBER;
update_count number;
prjt_name varchar2 not null := '01213264B';

cursor my_cur is 
    select sbt.table_name from sb_table sbt;

begin
   /* with sb_tables as (select table_name from all_tab_columns@db2 where 
    column_name = 'PROJECT_ID' and owner = 'SANDBOX'),
    project as (select project_id from sandbox.sb_project@db2 where 
    project_name = upper(prjt_name))*/


for tableName in my_cur
loop
  query := 'select count(t.project_id) into '|| update_count || 'from sandbox.' || tableName || '@db2 t, project p '||' where  t.project_id = p.project_id  ';
  Execute immediate query;
--into update_count;

if update_count <= 0 then
    query := 'DELETE FROM sb_tables where table_name = ' || tableName;
    execute immediate query ;
end if;

end loop;
end;
```

Comment: If I do that, I still get the same error, but I also get the additional text now. See Below:

ORA-06550: line 25, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   return returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <>
   and or like like2 like4 likec between into using || multiset
   bulk member submultiset
The symbol ";" was substituted for "IF" to continue.

Answer (score 0):

If you run it in sql-developer please note, there are different buttons for running query (green triangle) and running script (green smaller triangle over a white document). Use 'run script' button