# PL/SQL - I keep getting this error when concatenating: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I had another thread to get a different problem fixed and now I am stuck on another, seemingly simple, error. My cod is as follows:

```
declare
    update_count integer := 0;
    prjt_name varchar2(100) not null := '01213264B';
    cursor my_cur is (select table_name from all_tab_columns@adhoc_pos15 where column_name = 'PROJECT_ID' and owner = 'SANDBOX');
    tableName  my_cur%rowtype;
begin
    for tableName in my_cur
    loop
        update_count := 0;
      Execute immediate
        'select count(t.project_id) as "CNT" from sandbox.'
        || tableName
        || '@adhoc_pos15 t'
        || 'where  t.project_id = (select project_id from sandbox.sb_project@adhoc_pos15 where project_name = upper('
        || prjt_name
        || '))'
      into update_count;
      if update_count = 0 then
       execute immediate
            'DELETE FROM my_cur where table_name = '
            || tableName;
      end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

My error message is

```
ORA-06550: line 11, column 8:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
ORA-06550: line 10, column 6:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 20, column 8:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
ORA-06550: line 19, column 6:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

If you are interested. I will past a link to the previous error that I was getting below. You can see what the code originally looked like.

[Encountered 'Loop' Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652950/oracle-pl-sql-help-resolving-pls-00103-encountered-the-symbol-loop-when-exp?noredirect=1#comment80602754_46652950)

Edit 1: Per Valli's suggestions. I have updated my coding and get the error missing expression at line 15.

```
declare
    query varchar2(10000);
    update_count integer := 0;
    prjt_name varchar2(100) := '01213264B';
    cursor my_cur is (select table_name from all_tab_columns@db2where column_name = 'PROJECT_ID' and owner = 'SANDBOX');
    tableName  varchar2(100);
begin
  open my_cur;
    loop
    fetch my_cur into tableName;
    exit when my_cur%NOTFOUND;
        update_count := 0;
        execute immediate
        'select count(project_id) as "CNT" from sandbox.' || tableName || '@db2  '
        || ' where project_id = (select project_id from sandbox.sb_project@db2 where project_name = ''' || prjt_name || ''' ) '
        into update_count;
    if update_count > 0 then
     dbms_output.put_line (tableName);
    end if;
   end loop;
  close my_cur;
end;
```

I was missing an "=" symbol. This now runs. I get a few results than the error message

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04040: file ext_qsp_benefit.dat in DATA_DIR not found
ORA-02063: preceding 3 lines from ADHOC_POS15
ORA-06512: at line 13
```

Final Edit: Success! Apparently I cannot query certain tables. So I just took those tables out.

Final coding is:

```
declare
  query varchar2(10000);
  update_count integer := 0;
  prjt_name varchar2(100) := '01213264B';
  cursor my_cur is (select table_name from all_tab_columns@db2 where column_name = 'PROJECT_ID' and owner = 'SANDBOX' and table_name in ('X') );
  tableName  varchar2(100);
begin
  open my_cur;
    loop
    fetch my_cur into tableName;
    exit when my_cur%NOTFOUND;
        update_count := 0;
        execute immediate
        'select count(project_id) as "CNT" from sandbox.' || tableName || '@db2  '
        || ' where project_id = (select project_id from sandbox.sb_project@db2 where project_name = ''' || prjt_name || ''' ) '
        into update_count;
    if update_count > 0 then
      dbms_output.put_line (tableName);
    end if;
  end loop;
  close my_cur;
end;
```

This doesn't do exactly what I wanted. It sends the results to dbms_output. But It is a start! Thanks everyone for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that looks wrong is that `prjt_name` is a string, but you pass it as a number in your query. So here is what I would change:

```
    || 'where  t.project_id = (select project_id from sandbox.sb_project@adhoc_pos15 where project_name = upper('''
    || prjt_name
    || '''))'
```

This basically adds `' '` around the string value.

Then, since you get 2 errors from your execution, there must be an issue with the tableName. I rather use implicit cursor, but you should try to access the content of the cursor, like below:

```
    'select count(t.project_id) as "CNT" from sandbox.'
    || tableName.table_name
    || '@adhoc_pos15 t'
    || 'where  t.project_id = (select project_id from sandbox.sb_project@adhoc_pos15 where project_name = upper('''
    || prjt_name
    || '''))'
```

And you must remove that `delete` you do from your cursor... this looks completely wrong. The loop simply moves to the next records

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare
        update_count integer := 0;
        prjt_name varchar2(100) := '01213264B';
         tablename  varchar2(100);

        cursor my_cur is 
             select table_name 
                from all_tab_columns@adhoc_pos15 
               where column_name = 'PROJECT_ID' and owner = 'SANDBOX';
    begin
        OPEN my_cur;
        LOOP
         FETCH  my_cur into tableName;
           EXIT WHEN my_cur%NOTFOUND;
            update_count := 0;
             Execute immediate
                 'select count(t.project_id) as "CNT" from sandbox.' 
                || tableName
                || '@adhoc_pos15 t'
                || ' where  t.project_id in (select project_id from sandbox.sb_project@adhoc_pos15 where project_name = upper('
                || prjt_name
                || '))' 
                INTO update_count;
          if update_count = 0 then
           execute immediate
                'DELETE FROM my_cur where table_name = '
                || tablename;
          end if;
        end loop;
   CLOSE my_cur;
    end;
```

You have missed a concatenation at last. Some syntax errors too

Note:-

Why do you need a subquery here?

```
where  t.project_id in (select project_id from sandbox.sb_project@adhoc_pos15 where project_name = upper('
            || prjt_name
```

You can replace by

```
where t.project_name = prjt_name
```

Comment: I still get the same error message after  concatenating the "into" line  as you showed.

Comment: Why do use not null in declaration part. That doesnt work in plsql blok.

Comment: I need that sub query because the prjct_name is created and provided by the user. But our system turns that name into a number and the number is what is used to identify changes. I cannot depend on the end user to know how to figure out their project number.

Comment: Not sure why I was using not null. I removed it. still same error message.

Comment: I tried this is my editor and it compiled, ran successfully

Comment: When you use execute immediate, You will get PLS 00306 Errr when the query was not rightly formed.

Comment: My Query works fine when I run it by itself with a table in the place of tableName. 

    select count(t.project_id) as "CNT" from sandbox.temp_table@db2 t
    where  t.project_id = (select project_id from sandbox.sb_project@db2 
        where project_name = upper('01213264B'))

Comment: The way you fetch the tablename from the cursor seems giving the error.